# isotope jump on slow connections

Tags: javascript, jquery-isotope

I'm busy coding a site using isotope (v2), it loads images and it's responsive so the container is 100% wide. The images have different heights so there is some calculation involved for isotope.

The big problem is that on slower connections there is a jump between when the images are not loaded yet and when it's done loading.

If I float the items/blocks left, then they're sitting against each other until the gutter kicks in and if I remove the float they sit underneath each other until they pack in..

Is there any way that I can get it to display packed in without the jumps?

I hope this makes sense. :)

Edit: [Codepen with working example](http://codepen.io/thatgerhard/pen/EVPyzd)

```
Important note: Set throttling to "normal 3G" in chrome to see the problem
```

Comment: Show us your code, a way to reproduce the issue and what you tried to solve it... Then will have sense ;)

Comment: @gmo done, please see edit on original post

Comment: Tested with `3g (~20s)` and even in `2g (>1m)` but I don't see any *"jump"*... any way, to avoid your problem, I can suggest to use a "loading" image until each image is loaded on `DOM` content...I had a similar problem with Isotope time ago, and that was a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trigger layout after *each image* loads as you are now, initialize Isotope after *all images* have been loaded.

```
 var $grid = $('.grid').imagesLoaded( function() {
 // init Isotope after all images have loaded
 $grid.isotope({
 itemSelector: '.grid-item',
 percentPosition: true,
 masonry: {
  columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
  gutter: '.gutter-sizer'
 }
 });
 });
```